# Wonder if she will come or if she comes?

Tags: conditionals, present-tense

My grammar book says that I should use present tense forms in conditional clauses with words like "if" to talk about the future.

We won't be able to go out **if it rains**. (NOT will rain)

Now I wonder if I should use "present tense" when "if" means "whether", as well.

I wonder **if she will come** to my party this week.

I wonder **if she comes** to my party this week.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

For a single possible event or multiple possible events in the future, the modal construction is used:

- I wonder if/whether she will come to the series of lectures on social distancing next year[?]
- I doubt whether [/if, informally] they'll make it. [[Free Dictionary, forum](https://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst51696_I-wonder-whether-if-.aspx)]

More informally, the present participle is often used after 'be':

- I wonder if she is coming to my party this week[?]

But for a query or spoken internal question about the possibility of a habitual practice / occurrence / state, present simple is used:

- I wonder if/whether it snows *every* year in Bavaria? [the question mark prompts for a response, coding for a slight emphasis on the last four words; the italics code for the usual expected emphasis, extra to this]
- Mind you, I wonder if, at their age, they realise that kippers are smoked herrings. [[Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/i-wonder-if-whether)]

So here , 'will come' is required.

Comment: When asking about whether there is a previous plan or arrangement for her to come to my party this week, can the speaker say, "I wonder if she comes to my party this week."?

Comment: ... Sounds highly unnatural to my UK ears. Either non-native or over-high-falutin.

Comment: Is it because you can't think of a context where you're asking about a previous plan for her to come to my party this week? Or is it because you won't be saying that even in that kind of context? I do find it weird to say something like "I wonder if it rains next week", because there can't be any plan for it to rain next week.

Comment: "I wonder if she flies tomorrow./?" certainly sounds fine to me, and involves a possible existing  planned course of action. "I wonder if it rains tomorrow" sounds ghastly.

Comment: So it's the former reason. Thanks.